# 'stoi' was not declared in this scope still apperaing even adding -std=c++0x and custom function

Tags: c++

I am having problems using atoi, I tried adding `-std=c++0x`  and also tried to change atoi function with from_string

```
template <typename T> from_string(std::string const & s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T result;
    ss >> result;    // TODO handle errors
    return result;
}
```

but when using this I am getting

```
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|382|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'from_string' with no type [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|error: no matching function for call to 'from_string(std::basic_string<char>)'|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|note: candidate is:|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|382|note: template<class T> int from_string(const string&)|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|382|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|error: no matching function for call to 'from_string(std::basic_string<char>)'|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|note: candidate is:|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|382|note: template<class T> int from_string(const string&)|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|382|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Users\Eua\Desktop\cours\main.cpp|392|note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: return type missing for `from_string`

Comment: This code has nothing to do with `stoi`...

Comment: could you please help on pointing some more complete code to handle atoi?

Comment: Don't use this version of `from_string` inside a loop with many iterations... it is very very slow.  A couple dozen calls reading a config file you won't notice, but if you're using it to process a large datafile.... prepare to wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stoi` if you `#include <string>` and qualify it as belonging to the `std` namespace (`std::stoi`).

Your second error is caused by not having a return type for the function. Looks like you meant for it to return a `T`.

```
template <typename T>
/* return type goes here */ from_string(std::string const & s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T result;
    ss >> result;    // TODO handle errors
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify in the function you are returning a value `T`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
T from_string(std::string const & s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T result;
    ss >> result;    // TODO handle errors
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int x = from_string<int>("1");
    return 0;
}
```

in debug I see that `x=1`
so it works for me. show your code so we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: How can I add function basic_string<char> ? `'from_string(std::basic_string<char>)'` as I also get error: no matching function for call to 'from_string(std::basic_string<char>)'|

Comment: I have a function `static pair<size_t, size_t> key_to_idx(const string& key)
{
  size_t pos = key.find(",");
  string aux1 = key.substr(0, pos);
  string aux2 = key.substr(pos + 1);
  return make_pair(from_string(aux1), from_string(aux2));
}`  but when running that I am getting `error: no matching function for call to 'from_string(std::string&)'|`

Comment: changing string to basic_string<char> works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your function prototype does not define return type.  That is a problem.

```
template <typename T> 
   T from_string(std::string const & s) {
   std::stringstream ss(s);
   T result;
    ss >> result;    // TODO handle errors
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The function prototype does not define a return type.

Comment: I apologize for mis-stating my answer.  I am human.  It is updated.

Comment: Yup, that's why SO lets you edit your answer afterwards to make it better (I need that ability myself *all* the time)

Comment: Nicely stated @BenVoigt